# Is it a good practice to use decorator to convert all Unicode strings to binary strings?

Tags: python, unicode, decorator

Recently I wrote a little script to connect to servers via telnet (for some reason all the specific programs refused to connect).
The program was this:

```
import telnetlib
tn = telnetlib.Telnet('www.google.com',80)
tn.write('GET / HTTP/1.0\n')
tn.write('Host: www.google.com\n')
tn.write('User-agent: Chrome\n\n')
out = tn.read_all()
print(out)
```

It worked perfectly in Python 2.x.
But then I started using it in Python 3.x and encounter the problem, which was that all the strings as of Python 3.x are Unicode objects. So I started thinking how I can remedy it and came out with a solution using a decorator.

Actually I could have put `b` before every string (there were only few of them). But I wanted to do it as if it were a huge code snippet (just for training and using good code practice).

The solution with a decorator is the following:

```
def to_binary(f):
    def wrapper(self, *args):
        s,*args = args
        s = s.encode() #this line performs conversion to binary string
        return f(self, s, *args)
    return wrapper

telnetlib.Telnet.write = to_binary(telnetlib.Telnet.write)
```

My question is:

Is this a good solution to be used in the projects in the future by me? Or I had better prepend every string in `tn.write` with `b`, or maybe even use something else?

Answer (score 6):

It's a terrible solution, if for no other reason than it duplicates what one of the classes in the [`codecs`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/codecs.html#streamwriter-objects) module does.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what exactly does this in `codecs`? I'm also worried about decorating a method in the `telnet` module: `telnetlib.Telnet.write = to_binary(telnetlib.Telnet.write)`. Is it a good practice?

Comment: So you suggest just using `tn = codecs.getwriter('ascii')(telnetlib.Telnet('www.google.com',80))` instead of `tn = telnetlib.Telnet('www.google.com',80)`?

Comment: You won't be able to read from it if you do that, so wrap it separately.

Comment: Do you mean this: `tn_underlying = telnetlib.Telnet('www.google.com',80); 
tn = codecs.getwriter('ascii')(tn_underlying)` (so I can use them separately)?

Comment: OK! But this means that I would have to do this `tn = codecs.getwriter('ascii')(tn_underlying)` for each `telnetlib.Telnet` object. But using the decorator alters the `telnetlib.Telnet.write` for all the objects.

Comment: Can this approach with `codecs` be used with a decorator to apply the change to all the instances tinkering with the class (not each instance)?